# Python script wait before execution another script

Tags: python, bash, scripting, libtorrent

I have a bash script with various python scripts inside it, Which i guess should run one after another.

The first one is a script that download a torrent from a site and the second is a script that unrar the content.

The problem is that the unrar script doesnt wait for the torrent to be finished so i end up with only part of it.

Is there some way to tell the script to start only when torrent is complete?

Comment: You will need to provide some code or this is a guessing game.

Answer (score 1):

This is the bash script.  dwtor.py download the torrent,  unrar.py obviously unrar the content.. And so on..

```
#!/bin/bash

python dwtor.py                       

python unrar.py    

cd P2                                                 

python /home/disk/user/pyrocore/
```

Comment: Why are you not pushing everything in a python script as suggested above? Otherwise this is a bash issue and you can use parenthesis in your script and the if case like:                                                                   if ( echo "your_first_script" );then echo "WAS OK...second_script";else echo "error message";fi
Again better ways and control you can find directly in python. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing a script using os.system, then an EASY solution might be 
import os

```
if (os.system("python script whatever") == 0):
    print("Your script was terminated and here you can add the rest)
else:
    print("Execution errors and do something else")
```

Otherwise you can check other answer like subprocess module :-)

Please let me know if this help.